# Store image in memory then write to disk

Tags: python, opencv

This program snippet cuts objects recognized by color from the video frame and saves them to disk.
Distinguishes different objects with a full save path and objectID. Because I want to store pictures of different objects in a separate folder.
This has worked well so far. However, for high-resolution images, continuous disc burning completely freezes the program.

I would ask for your help on how to temporarily store the cropped images and their names in memory and write them to disk at the end of the program.

I mean bypass the `cv.imwrite(os.path.join(path + cwd + str(objectID), fileName), crop_img)` as long as the program is busy cropping the images.

```
path = os.getcwd()
cwd = "/Data/"

for (objectID, centroid) in objects.items():
      # draw both the ID of the object and the centroid of the
      # object on the output frame
      text = "ID {}".format(objectID)
      cv.putText(frame, text, (centroid[0], centroid[1] - 20),
                 cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 0, 0), 2)
      cv.circle(frame, (centroid[0], centroid[1]), 2, (255, 0, 0), -1)

      # coordinates for cropping
      ext_left = centroid[0] - 70
      ext_right = centroid[0] + 70
      ext_top = centroid[1] - 70
      ext_bot = centroid[1] + 70

      crop_img = frame[ext_top:ext_bot, ext_left:ext_right]

      createFolder(path + cwd + str(objectID))
      fileName = '%s.jpg' % (str(objectID) + str(uuid.uuid4()))
      try:
          cv.imwrite(os.path.join(path + cwd + str(objectID), fileName), crop_img)
      except:
          pass
```

Comment: What sort of a machine are you running on? What OS? How many cores? Decent disks? Have you considered multi-processing or multi-threading? Do you have a decent amount of RAM? You could `imencode()` your images and append them to a list? How long do you need to run?

Comment: One trick I've used for processing videos is to create a huge numpy array containing all of the uncompressed frames concatenated after one another. The you can use `numpy.save` and `numpy.load` to load it. The `load` function has options for loading the array with `mmap` which is useful in some circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an list and append each cropped image to it, as you create them, like this:

```py
crop_imgs = []
for (objectID, centroid) in objects.items():
   ...
   crop_img = frame[ext_top:ext_bot, ext_left:ext_right]
   crop_imgs.append((objectID, crop_img))
```

We append a tuple of both the `objectID` and the image itself. You could also use a `dict`, if you prefer.

Then separate your writing loop here:

```py
for (objectID, crop_img) in crop_imgs:
    createFolder(path + cwd + str(objectID))
    fileName = '%s.jpg' % (str(objectID) + str(uuid.uuid4()))
    try:
        cv.imwrite(os.path.join(path + cwd + str(objectID), fileName), crop_img)
    except:
        pass
```

However, consider the drawbacks of your proposal:

The overall runtime of your program will remain the same, but now you will not get intermediate results written to disk. If the program crashes, you'll lose everything, and can't resume it without starting over.

Unlike in a video file, the images will be stored in memory with no compression. There's no point in letting available memory go unused, but if you exhaust available memory, the operating system has to [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging) the memory to disk, which will be slower than if you had just written out the compressed JPEGs at each step.

By the way, even without modifying the code, you could use a [RAM disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive), which is a virtual filesystem that exists only in RAM, then copy the results to your hard disk. The same caveats apply.

You could potentially get speed gains from using the `threading` or `multiprocessing` libraries to add processed video frames to a queue and have another thread/process perform the encoding to JPEG.

Another minor improvement: Use an incrementing number instead of a UUID. Generating lots of random numbers can be slow.

Comment: My thoughts exactly!